# Vertically centering a UL inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div style="background: Red; height: 100px;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to vertically center the ul in the div but I'm not sure how. 
[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JzuFT/) Can anyone advise me on this.

Marilou

Comment: If it's more than one line of content with dynamic width/height, you may have to bite the bullet and use a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS does not support vertical centering of arbitrary block elements.  However, there are many "hacks" that will let you "make it work".

You can set the parent div to display:inline.  However, you will then have issues with your height and background color.

W3C Link:  http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

One hack that will do it: (has a great explanation too) http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 11):

You could always use `display: table-cell;` in combination with `vertical-align: middle;`:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {

    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

}
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/HSXcy/)***

Comment: "Note: The values "inline-table", "run-in", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values."

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: But, we all hope IE7 and IE8 go away quickly. ;)

Comment: This worked good inside the div but upset the way the outer div appeared on my page. I should mention that the outer div is part of other code. Thanks for taking the time to mention this suggestion. I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: What's the !DOCTYPE setting for IE9? Actually I'm waiting for IE10 as they still didn't fix gradients like every other browser has. Why is MS so slow at coming out with a browser that works like all the rest?

Comment: Well, Marilou, it does shrink-wrap and force you to add a width.  But, I'm sure that could easily be fixed.  It's the most viable way to align vertically in a div without changing your div to a table.

Comment: @Marilou I am not sure about MS... I think the IE team just needs to start using Webkit. :P

Comment: @Marilou You should be able to use any DOCTYPE.  I think the idea is to get IE out of quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS position property

```
#ulid{position:relative; top:50%; left: 50%;}

pass the id to ul
<ul id="ulid">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JzuFT/9/

Comment: Depending on the size of the UL, that won't always work, and can get complicated.

Comment: I tried this but it centers the top of the ul at 50%. I need the center of the ul to be at the 50% point.

Comment: @marilou - as scott suggested this method is not very straightforward and has to be adjusted for every <li> element, but is very powerful method, but yea will get complicated. Use margin-left:<value should be -ve(width of ul element /2) and margin-top should be -ve(width of ul element/2) http://jsfiddle.net/JzuFT/22/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/S8cj5/

Adding an inner span prior to the <li> inner text 
is something I've found quite useful in the past for 
vertically positioning an <li>.

Comment: @Scott - ...but I've found it to be reliable across browsers and across browser versions, so it's a very small price to pay, in my view.